# numpy searchsorted to return nan if there is no suitable index instead of "0 or N"

Tags: python, numpy, binary-search, numpy-slicing

## Context

Currently, `numpy.searchsorted()` will:

> *"if there is no suitable index, return either 0 or N"*

I will be performing multiple indexing and subsetting operations on the original unsorted `a` using the indices generated like so:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
start = np.array([0.0,1.0,3.0,3.0,5.0,6.0])
stop = np.array([1.0,3.0,3.0,5.0,6.0,7.0])

starts = np.searchsorted(a, start, side="left")
stops = np.searchsorted(a, stop, side="right")
length = range(len(starts))
indices = [np.arange(starts[i], stops[i] + 1) for i in length]
```

*NOTE: The actual code uses 3 different `numpy.ndarray` (single above represented as `a`), one for each column of a 2D array (from a `pandas.DataFrame`).*

## Task

**I would like to perform the binary search to ultimately return the rows of the original unsorted array (one for each element of `(start, stop)`.**

My approach is to use the return of `np.argsort()`, intersect the indices that satisfy the conditions for each search on the 3 columns (1D arrays), and then subset to retrieve the original values, not only from the input arrays of `searchsorted()` but other columns of the original unsorted 2D array (hence indices are required to get those rows).

As `searchsorted()` returns `0` or `a.shape[0]`, it will result in creating a subset that contains all values with `np.arange()`. However, given my current approach, this is not suitable.

How can I return `nan` from `saerchsorted()` so that subsequent subsetting will return empty, or is there an alternative method to achieve the task?

I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You seem to have intervals, are they always contiguous and non-overlapping?

Comment: @mozway I would like to return all indices (i.e. to relate back to the rows in the 2D) in between `starts[i], stops[i]`. The values of those arrays can be considered random and not necessarily consecutive (as was illustrated in the simplified example). Additionally, they may contain duplicates, so for this case I would like to filter all that lie between the first and last occurence. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: *EDIT: regarding handling of duplicates I meant to say "I would like to filter all of `a` that satisfy the condition and lie between `start` and `stop`.*